# Is there a way to get the originating app from a universal link?

Tags: swift, ios-universal-links

I have an IOS app that handles Universal links exactly as expected, parses up queryItems and does the right thing. 
Most of my users will be using Universal Links from iBooks but it's possible the link could be from a note in the Notes app, or some other app where you can paste in a link. What I do now is provide a 'Back to iBooks' link using an NSURL "ibooks://" (not fool proof, but it works for most cases). And this works fine as it takes the user back to the page in iBooks where they tapped on the Universal Link. What I would like to do is provide a 'Back to xxx' link in my app that goes back to any calling app so if someone tapped on a link in Notes then in my app it would provide a "Back to Notes" link. I don't see any way in the userActivity object to discover the original calling app.

I've explored the userActivity object, read the docs but nothing seems to have what I need. getContinuationStreams looks promising but not much documentation about it.

Comment: iOS added a "Back to [previous app]" button in the upper left corner a while ago.  Doesn't this accomplish what you want without you having to try to replicate it?

Comment: slapping forehead....thanks. I hadn't noticed that. It is exactly what I wanted.